# How to create an iMessage style screen?

Tags: react-native

Here is a condensed version of my code:

```
    const MessagingScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightblue', height: 56 + topInsetHeight, position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }}>
        {/* Top banner content */}
      </View>
  
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <FlatList
      inverted
      data={/* Your message data */}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text>{item.message}</Text>
      )}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingHorizontal: 8,
            paddingBottom: 56,
            paddingTop: 64 + bottomInsetHeight + 20,
                            }}
    />

    <View style={{ 
      backgroundColor: primaryDark,
      paddingTop: 8,
      paddingBottom: 8 + bottom,
      alignItems: "center",
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      width: "100%",
      maxHeight: 200,
      }}>
      {/* Bottom text input */}
      <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        placeholder="Type your message..."
      />
    </View>
  </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
</View>
```

);
};

Here is the problem: If the FlatList only has a few datapoints the FlatList still scrolls up when the TextInput is focused. I always want the TextInput to move above the keyboard but I only want the FlatList to move up if its content will be covered by the keyboard. I've been trying to figure this out for months and have asked chatGPT in many different ways and still haven't been able to figure it out. Does anyone know if this can be done and if so how? Thanks.

In the top 2 pictures you can see that only the TextInput moves up and the content of the FlatList doesn't. In the bottom 2 pictures both of them move up together.

[image]

Comment: Could you share screenshots or images of exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want mine to do what the screenshots show. Mine only does what the bottom 2 screenshots show regardless of how many items are in the FlatList. @JBrown

Comment: Have you tried dynamically resizing the flatlist when the keyboard is open? For instance, it might take 90% of the view height normally, but shrink to only take up the height that remains when the keyboard opens. I don't have time to write out a solution at the moment but that is the approach I would take.